# Build Android App with Old Manifest Package Name

Tags: android, react-native, expo

When I build an Android app, there's an error message shown like this

> Package 'grwe.android.package' from AndroidManifest.xml is not a valid Java package name as 'package' is a Java keyword

but, I've already had an app that was published on Google Play Store before with that manifest package name,

So, what should I do right now?

I built android app using EAS (Expo & React Native)

Answer (score 0):

Your `applicationId` does not necessarly need to match the source code.

Keep your `applicationId` as the published one in your `gradle build file`.

```
// build.gradle.kts

defaultConfig {
    applicationId = "grwe.android.package"
        ...
}
```

Organize your kotlin/java source code in package like `grwe.android.packer` or `grwe.android.packager`

```kotlin
package com.example.codes

class SomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    ...
}
```

Android System will launch your activity like

```sh
androidApplicationId/fullQualifiedClassNameForActivity

grwe.android.package/com.example.codes.SomeActivity

grwe.android.package/net.example.OtherActivity
```

Hope, it helps.